# .ctor is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, constructor, ambiguity

I am replicating a situation that I am facing.

Let's say we have an assembly, with C# class as:

```
public class Program
{
    int n = 0;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }

    public Program()
    {
    }

    public Program(int num = 10)
    {
        n = num;
    }
}
```

We refer the above assembly in VB.NET project and trying to create an instance of the Program class:

```
Module Module1 
    Sub Main()
        Dim p As New Program()
        p.Print()
        p = New Program(20)
        p.Print()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The VB.NET project is not compiling, giving error:

**'.ctor' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'ConsoleApplication2.Program'.**

From the error message we can see the the VB.NET compiler is not sure which constructor to call - as one constructor is parameterless and other with one optional parameter. This issue is occurring in VS2010/.NET 4 and not in VS2012/.NET 4.5. Also in C# it is not givng any issues, it successfully compiles and runs the code of object initiaization of Program class.

Is there a way we can create Program class' instance in VB.NET + VS2010/.NET 4 without changing the constructors ?

Comment: Why do you want this construct? Is there a way that I'm missing that you can actually invoke the second constructor and have the compiler use the default parameter?

Comment: This code smells. It is ambitious without `VB`. What do you think `num` value should be for a use like `var program = new Program()`? Did you *optionally* want `num` to be `10` or is it default constructor where `num` is *field initialized* to be `0`???

Comment: @Sinatr, this is a replication of a situation that I am facing. I wrote it that way so that I can differentiate the output and identify which constructor was getting called in C#.

Comment: It sounds like the VB compiler is doing you a favour to me.

Comment: @Jodrell, fully agree, we should have it in C# as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the definitions of your constructors in the `Program` class

Because the argument to the second is optional, then both are candidates when calling using `New Program()`. This creates the ambiguity.

Instead, define your constructors using this sort of pattern:

```
public Program()
    : this(10)
{
}

public Program(int num)
{
    n = num;
}
```

or just the single constructor:

```
public Program(int num = 10)
{
    n = num;
}
```

(Personally I prefer the first of these).

Comment: @Jon_Egerton the change in constructor will sort the issue, but can we call the specific constructor without making any changes in the C# `Program` class ? 
Also, the ambiguity doesn't occur in C#, but occurs in VB.NET. Also in VB.NET it occurs in .NET 4.0 and not .NET 4.5

Comment: Frankly, not sure - I have seem ambiguities slip through before, or start erroring after a while. However look at it another way. When you call "New Program()" what are you expecting for `n`? - 0 or 10? They're not just ambiguous at the code level, but at the "notional" level too.

Comment: When you say .Net 4, was that in VS2010 or VS2012/13?

Comment: See [Damien's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21906563/592111). In C# it would have been handled for all these versions. For VB its a recent addition. Still a rubbish construct though - you'll never get the default of 10!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to change the implementation of the constructor as also [@JonEgerton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21904907/642579) wrote. If this is not possible, you could try the following - not really beautiful - workarounds:

- If you know the inner implementation of the Program class, you can simply call the constructor with the int-Parameter with the value that the parameterless constructor assigns, in your sample `Dim p As New Program(0)`. This implies that you need to be careful regarding later changes in the implementation of the constructors of the `Program` class as they will not be reflected in your implementation. For instance, if the implementors of the `Program` class change the value that is assigned in the parameterless constructor, your solution will still assign a value of 0.
- As C# seems to handle the creation differently, you can also add a C# class (e.g. in a C# class library) that creates the instance of program for you and returns it to your code. Though this maybe means to add a class library to your solution for this sole purpose and therefore is not really a beautiful approach, later changes in the implementation of the `Program` class will be reflected in your program also.