# Inconsistencies in compiler ambiguity errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, compiler-construction, ambiguity

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21904767/592111), the following class is defined:

```
public class Program
{
    int n = 0;

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }

    public Program()
    {
    }

    public Program(int num = 10)
    {
        n = num;
    }
}
```

Now, obviously a call to the constructor here using `new Program()` is ambiguous due to the optional parameter on the second constructor. When reading this its not clear whether `n` should be initialized with `0` or `10`.

However:

Actual reporting of the problem seems inconsistent. Setting up this class and using it I was able to use `new Program()` in either C#, or VB.Net, and in .Net 4 or .Net 4.5. All tests were done in VS2013.

In the linked question though, the OP actually got the error message when using VB.Net IN .NET 4 and VS2010:

> '.ctor' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in class 'ConsoleApplication2.Program'.

So why is the error there sometimes while at other times the program can be executed successfully?

For reference the value of `n` when the execution is successful is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the VB language changed between versions 10 and [11](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039). In the Version 11 Language Specification, Section 11.8.1. Tie breaking rule 7.9 was added:

> 7.9.  If M did not use any optional parameter defaults in place of explicit arguments, but N did, then eliminate N from the set.

(As were rules 7.8 and 7.10, but irrelevant here)

Comment: Was just beginning the hunt for that in the spec - assumed it must be there somewhere, so thanks for saving me that!

Answer (score 0):

For VS2012 and VS2013 is defined:

> **Overload Resolution**
>
> Use of named and optional arguments affects overload resolution in the following ways:
>
> - A method, indexer, or constructor is a candidate for execution if each of its parameters either is optional or corresponds, by name or by position, to a single argument in the calling statement, and that argument can be converted to the type of the parameter.
> - If more than one candidate is found, overload resolution rules for preferred conversions are applied to the arguments that are explicitly specified. Omitted arguments for optional parameters are ignored.
> - If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That would explain it, except that I can't see any different between the VS2010 definition (which is the one you actually linked), and the VS2012/2013 versions of the same.

Comment: Uh... you beat me by a few minutes. Well as I mentioned in my post, i think the difference is not within the CS20XX versions but, how VB and C# deal with it.